# Dash app callback doesn't seem to return anything

Tags: python, mongodb, jupyter-notebook, pymongo, plotly-dash

The app layout displays everything just fine when "app" is called at the bottom. However, when I enter my username, password, and click the button, nothing changes. It's not a database issue, I tried immediately returning a test list in the  @app callback and it didn't show up in the app layout div. However I can hard code whatever I need to in the app layout div. So I'm confident its an issue with the @app callback function. Again don't overthink the username/password, I've tested with variables outside the database. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwyEA.png)

Comment: Just from taking a quick glance of `cb_render` I can see that attributes `userValue`, `passValue` and `buttonValue` are greyed out so they are not used in the function call. So why do you expect anything to change?

Comment: Pavel, thank you for responding, I should have specified I'm actually running this in Jupyter. I pasted it in that IDE for the screenshot. They don't look like that in Jupyter

Comment: I can also put " return ["test"]" outside the if statement so parameters wouldn't matter but it won't display  "test" in the dashboard.